# How secure is passing an ajax request to a Codeigniter controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to securely pass an ajax request response to my codeigniter application. I currently have something like this

Javascript

```
    var dataString = {
    'id' : id
};
var submit = $.ajax({
    url:$('#hiddenurl').val() + 'index.php?/reports/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: dataString,
    success: function(msg){
        location.reload();

    },
    error: function(msg){
        alert("fail");
    }
 });
```

My question is how safe is this method? is there a better solution to it? also is this a safe solution to pass login details? or do you guru's have a better solution?

Thank you.

Comment: ^ Yes if you don't call a secure url (SSL) then all your data will be visible over the pipe.

Comment: Precisely as secure as doing a regular form submit through the browser.

Comment: Can someone provide a little light in to how I go about implementing ssl into a codeigniter app? Is it really about just using https:// instead of http:// for ajax call urls? or is there more to it? This is assuming I've gotten myself a signed cert.

Comment: that's all there is to it. mostly it's about the $$$

Comment: @dandavis are you being serious? whats a good vendor for purshing a ssl cert?

Comment: it's expensive and sometimes a bear to setup (especially with load balancers), but once it's up, you should be able to just add the "s" to you full urls and everything should just work. I can't vouch for any vendors, but if your hosting provider offers it, that would probably be the easiest to install.

Comment: do note that if the login page is using http:// and your app url is using https://, your data will still be susceptible to attacks by tools like [sslstrip](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/)

Answer (score 0):

Both AJAX request and the traditional form submission happening through HTTP request. So both are having the same security level.

The HTTP security can be improve by having SSL for your website.